# No columns generated in datagridview if empty query in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
Stops_BindingSource = new BindingSource();
dgvStops.DataSource = Stops_BindingSource;            
Trips_Context.Tripstops.Load();

long Id = (long)dgvTrips.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value;
Stops_BindingSource.DataSource = Trips_Context.Tripstops.Local.ToBindingList().Where(x => x.Tripid == Id);
```

If the query returns records then dgvStops has columns created, if empty, then no columns (or new record row) is created.  Do I need to add something

Comment: I deleted all reocods in Tripstops then I changed my code as follows:
...
From:
            this.Stops_BindingSource.DataSource = Trips_Context.Tripstops.Local.ToBindingList().Where(x => x.Tripid == Id);
To:
            this.Stops_BindingSource.DataSource = Trips_Context.Tripstops.Local.ToBindingList();
...

Comment: Eliminating the .Where makes it work as expected.  Any ideas of how else I can filter the results in the datagridview?

Comment: Solved by filtering in grid.  Using row.visible